# Why aren't these Xpath elements an array?

Tags: php, arrays, xpath

So this works fine in a foreach which I thought meant $elements was an array...

```
$DOM = new DOMDocument(); 
$DOM->loadHTML($content);
$xpath = new DOMXPath($DOM);
$elements= $xpath->query('//li');

foreach($elements as $element){
    $newdoc = new DOMDocument();
    $cloned = $element->cloneNode(TRUE);
    $newdoc->appendChild($newdoc->importNode($cloned,TRUE));
    $lis .= $newdoc->saveHTML();
}
```

But this

```
if ($elements[0]) {
    echo $elements[0]->nodeValue;   
}
```

Gives  `Cannot use object of type DOMNodeList as array`

The foreach() there is not a class method so why does it function on the DOMNodeList as if it were an array when apparently it is not one?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's all perfectly explained in the php documentation: the [`DOMNodeList`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/class.domnodelist.php) class implements the [`Iterator`](http://php.net/manual/en/class.iterator.php) interface, which allows the use of [`foreach`](http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.foreach.php) on objects of that class.

Note that you can use the `item` method to access any elements of the list by index:

```
$elements->item(0)->nodeValue
```

Comment: Thank you.  I'll take a closer look at the docs.  Using DOMDocument and Xpath for the first time

Answer (score 0):

My guess is that php's foreach function knows how to iterate objects besides arrays, but in terms of getting an array from the DomNodeList, use this:

```
$arr = [];
foreach ($elements as $element) {
    $arr[] = $element;
}
echo $arr[0]->nodeValue;
```